# Overloaded methods with optional parameters?

Tags: java, overloading

If I am overloading a method and decide to give one an optional parameter:

```
public static void method(int a, double b, String... c){
    //method
}


public static void method(int a, double b, string c, string d){
    //method
}

public static void main(String[] args){
method.(int, double, string, string);
}
```

The ellipsis indicates zero or more strings for the first method, and the second method takes two strings. If I call the method and input two strings, which method is invoked?

EDIT: I've been testing this, but I keep getting a compiler error searching for an identifier before the parameters but after the dot. Being (very) new to Java, what is an identifier, and how does it apply to these methods?

Comment: How hard can it be to write two extra lines of code and execute it yourself.

Comment: You know you can write this code in an IDE and test the results, right?

Comment: Just because you can test this, I don't think it deserves so many downvotes. Programmers may find this useful in future, as it's quicker to google something than test it.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I actually agree with the down votes since I didn't test and then ask WHY it was behaving this way. I was too quick to ask without providing any prior resources. If people find it useful they will up vote.

Comment: As for your compiler error, remove the dot from your method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Some More Illustrations:**

The other answer is good , but I thought It needs to be illustrated more [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/autoboxing-and-unboxing):

*JAVA* decides which method to call from several overloaded methods by **widening / boxing / varargs** sequence search in the following way:

- Widening beats Boxing
- Widening beats Varargs
- Boxing beats Varargs

That is:

Widening > Boxing > Variable args

so methods with variable args are called as a last option.

### **Some Explanations:**

Boxing is Conversion of a primitive type to the corresponding reference type i.e.:

```
int -> Integer
byte -> Byte
```

Widening is transforming a variable into a wider type i.e.:

```
String -> Object
int -> long
```

So *JAVA* uses this to enlarge the scope of its matching process through the overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1):

Java will call a method with a varags parameter ONLY if there is no alternative. So the method with no varags parameters will be called when you pass 2 `String`s.

Comment: What is an *ellipsis* method?

Comment: @ortis. you already gave the answer. You didn't gave Ely a chance to investigate something and enjoy the result. ;)

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza: A method where the last argument can be present zero or more times.

Comment: Actually, I did investigate before I read this. I got a compiler error instead. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Conffusion: true. Although, trying it yourself will not give you the info that Java call ellipsis in last resort